# What's is this part?

Tags: fastener, lawnmower, john-deere, compatibility, connector

[image]This appears to possibly be for a piece of farm equipment. I have no idea what it does. If any one out there can help I would really appreciate it.

[image]g

Comment: It's a bi-swivel mount of some sort ... but I guess that part was obvious.

Comment: I know I've seen this exact assembly before.  
Where'd you obtain it?

Comment: I found it at a second hand store and thought we could use it.  Turns out nobody in my family knows what it is.  Thought it would be for a tractor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not part of a vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't think it's a car part. I think it's a bi-swivel mount for a flag stanchion so you can get it *at just the right angle* from anywhere. You know, for those decorative flags people put out on the front of their house? I did a cursory glance and didn't find anything which looked *exactly* like it ...

Comment: I think it's for an elbow of an adjustable lamp

Comment: @DucatiKiller - It could be that as well. I just don't think it's a car part is all.